# Add a different cell & formula for each row in parsed table

Tags: php, dom, xpath, html-table, sum

I'm currently parsing specific columns of a table via simple_html_dom. Which works fine. I now want to add an extra column after that group with a calculation-formula for each row. It is also important that it works with various row-numbers, cause each table could have a different amount of rows.

```
It should work like this:
<external htmt table parsed via simple_html_dom>< - should be added into the array ->
row(1) = column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | do nothing this is header
row(2) =   cell1 |   cell2 |   cell3 |   cell4 | sum cell 2 to 4 of row(2)
row(n) =   cell1 |   cell2 |   cell3 |   cell4 | sum cell 2 to 4 of row(n)
```

I thought about adding Dom Document into the code when I echo the $td cells.

```
// cells of row    
echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
// now new cell at the end of row
echo '<td>';
// now adding calculation via Dom
        $file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. 'URL';
        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        $doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
// Sum Column 2 + 3 + 4 of row 2 (in this example, different below)
        print $xpath->evaluate('(//table/tr[2]/td[2])+(//table/tr[2]/td[3])+(//table/tr[2]/td[4])');
// closing cell and row
echo ' mio $</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

This actually works, but obviously only with row 2. So each row now has the sum for row 2 at the end. Is there any way to calculate it for each row differently?

This is the whole code currently

```
    // Table 6 - Contracts
$table6 = $html->find('table', 6);
$rowData1 = array();
    $columnNumbers = [ 3, 4, 5, 6];
foreach($table6->find('tr') as $row) {
    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $flight1 = array();
        foreach($row->find('td') as $columnNumber => $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        if ( in_array( $columnNumber, $columnNumbers ) ) {
    $flight1[] = $cell->plaintext;
}
    }
    foreach($row->find('th') as $columnNumber => $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        if ( in_array( $columnNumber, $columnNumbers ) ) {
     $flight1[] = $cell->plaintext;
}    }
    $rowData1[] = $flight1;
}
foreach ($rowData1 as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($tr as $td)
        echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
echo '<td>';
// now adding calculation via Dom
    $file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. 'URL';
        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        @$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
// Sum Column 4 + 5 + 6 of row 2
        print $xpath->evaluate('(//table[td/u/b/.="Contracts"]/tr[2]/td[4])+(//table[td/u/b/.="Contracts"]/tr[2]/td[5])+(//table[td/u/b/.="Contracts"]/tr[2]/td[6])');
// closing cell and row
echo ' mio $</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>
```

Comment: *"This actually works"* - Not the way it was posted it won't since it contains many parse errors. Can you reformat the code? Stack's code highlighting is getting thrown off.